# Mongoose - how to create portable documents with fixed type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given the goal of having a JSON object that can be passed to a consumer where the json object contains some variation of:

```
{
    _id: 1
    name:  "my_name",
    type: "my_type",
    my_particulars:  {
      value: 1,
      author: "some author"
    }
}
```

such that the "type" value is locked into the schema/model is there an established pattern for satisfying this requirement?

It seems to me that the best options is some form of:

```
var WidgetSchema = new Schema({
  //Name
  name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  type: {type: String, required: true, default: "widget"},
  title: {type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  //Status 1: Not Live
  //Status 2: Live
  status: {type: Number, required: true, default: 1}
});

WidgetSchema.virtual('type').set(
function () {
  return false;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with _value is locked into the schema/model_ ? It'll never change?

Comment: Yes exactly.   The idea is that at any point in time, and any location within the system the system(s) should be able to treat a document as a statically typed thing.    

In essence, layering type reflection onto the resulting JSON objects stored in the documents.

`WidgetsSchema {
   type: { type: String, default: "widget" }
};

GizmosSchema {
  type: {type: String, default: "gizmo"}
};`

Comment: if it's truly static why not just define something static on the model/schema?  `WidgetSchema.my_type = "widget"`

Comment: simply because I'm not fully sure I understand how that would populate across all circumstances.  would this be mapped to all of the documents associated with this schema?

I.e. if I pull a document, send it to a consumer, will the my_type value be sent as part of that operation.  If not known, I can test.

Comment: You can define it as a virtual getter then specify that virtuals are sent when `toJSON` is called on the object.

Comment: That's the sort of strategy I was looking for.  If you could provide that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of actually storing the type you can add it as a virtual property which is returned with the JSON.  Something like:

```
WidgetSchema.virtual('type').get(function () {
  return 'widget';
});
```

With this defined, you can instruct mongoose to include virtuals in the toObject/toJSON output by passing the `virtuals` option.

```
// either directly to the method
instanceOfWidget.toJSON({virtuals: true});

// or as a default by setting the option on the schema
WidgetSchema.set('toObject', {virtuals: true});
```